# Grails + RESTful URL mapping + Filters + Routes

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Member have many jobs. A member can add, delete or update Jobs. Currently there are actions (add, delete or update) defined in a controller which are called through jQuery.ajax(). We are sending job id and member id to perform the operation. Member id is necessary because there is a role admin who can modify the job on behalf of members, so we need to identify the member. But sending member id is dangerous as anyone can send the request by modifying the member id.

I know, we can add constraint do restrict that only admin can modify the jobs or a member can modify only his jobs. My question is, Do I need to add these constraints in the action of the controller or Is there any Grails way to do that. I have google, the same thing is handled in Ruby and Rails by using routes. And in grails I have skim through RESTful URL mapping, which is perhaps used for this purpose.

Can anyone points me to right direction, thanks. I am using Grails 2.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement some realization of `AbstractPersistenceEventListenerService` to not allow perform actions with entity that constains id of not logged in user. Example:

```
class MultiTenantPersistenceEventListenerService extends AbstractPersistenceEventListenerService {
    def springSecurityService
    @Override
    protected  AbstractPersistenceEventListener createPersistenceEventListener(Datastore datastore) {
        return new MultiTenantPersistenceEventListener(datastore)
    }
}
class MultiTenantPersistenceEventListener extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener {
    MultiTenantPersistenceEventListener(final Datastore datastore) {
        super(datastore)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPersistenceEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
         def entity = event.getEntityObject() // could be your Job domain entity
         def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() //current logged in user
         if(entity.hasProperty('userId')){  // every job belongs to User
            if(entity.userId != user.id){
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Acces Denied !")   
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is some interesting stuff, I am currently trying SPEL expression. Will try that too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recomment to use grails **spring-security-plugin**. There is a lot of information in web about plugin and it's easy configurable. Plugin allows you to perfrom controller's action in secure way. For example:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
def followAjax = { ... }

@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
def personal = { ... }
```

For more information - [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [spring-security with grails](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/).

Comment: Can I add a method in case of role. For instance @Secured(['checkSecured()'])

Comment: No. You should add corresponding role to user to allow him perform some action and then check this role by annotation in controller. All roles defined in UserRole table, so you can add new roles with ease.

Comment: Adding new role for each user for an action, will increase the rows in the UserRole table. For instance if I give a role to user on login like ROLE_12USERID, so doing this for each user will increase the size of UserRole Table. What you say ?

Comment: Nope. You can add the same role for many users. And each user can have many roles.

Comment: But that does not solve the problem, still a member can delete others job.

Comment: That's true. I have another answer for you below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Authorize attribute to authorize the user, 
e.g

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles=SiteRoles.Admin|SiteRoles.HelpDesk)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

This is a nice approach for making website secure.

go through these link, this will help you.

[custom authorization with asp.net mvc](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/)

[asp.net mvc authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using grails my dear. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: oops sorry. I missed that.